# What is the device in the middle?

Tags: networking, ip, traceroute

I did a traceroute on an IP address and got these results. I am only showing hop 9, 10 and 11, where it crosses over from my provider to their provider:

```
9    13 ms    13 ms    16 ms  host213-121-193-95.ukcore.bt.net [213.121.193.95]
10    24 ms    13 ms    12 ms  194.74.65.22
11    18 ms    23 ms    18 ms  brhm-bb-1c-ae5-0.network.virginmedia.net [212.250.15.209]
```

What is the device in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whois 194.74.65.22

```
inetnum:        194.74.65.0 - 194.74.65.255
netname:        BT-UKIP-IPV4-INFRASTRUCTURE
descr:          Private Circuit Customer Networks
country:        GB
admin-c:        BS1474-RIPE
tech-c:         BS1474-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
remarks:        Please send abuse notification to abuse@bt.net
remarks:        New netname
remarks:        INFRA-AW
mnt-by:         BTNET-MNT
mnt-lower:      BTNET-MNT
mnt-routes:     BTNET-MNT
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '194.72.0.0/14AS2856'

route:          194.72.0.0/14
descr:          BTnet
origin:         AS2856
mnt-by:         BTNET-MNT
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.67.4 (WHOIS2)
```

Comment: I guess that means it is one of BT's devices.